# How can I use the jQuery Zoomy plugin in catalog product_list Prestashop

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop

I want to make like here http://www.templatemonster.com/prestashop-themes.php. I add this script sunsean.com/zoomi/zoomi.js in header and then change product_list

```
    <div class="center_block">
        <a href="{$product.link|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" class="product_img_link" title="{$product.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">
            <img class="zoomi" src="{$link->getImageLink($product.link_rewrite, $product.id_image, 'home_default')}" alt="{$product.legend|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" {if isset($homeSize)} width="{$homeSize.width}" height="{$homeSize.height}"{/if} />
                {if isset($product.new) && $product.new == 1}<span class="new">{l s='New'}</span>{/if}
        </a>
        <h3>
            <a href="{$product.link|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" title="{$product.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">{$product.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'|truncate:35:'...'}
            </a>
        </h3>
            <p class="product_desc">
                <a href="{$product.link|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" title="{$product.description_short|strip_tags:'UTF-8'|truncate:360:'...'}" >{$product.description_short|strip_tags:'UTF-8'|truncate:360:'...'}
                </a>
            </p>
    </div>
```

But it doesn't work. Here what I have:

```
<img class="zoomi" width="124" height="124" alt="" src="http://kids.int/img/p/1/5/15-home_default.jpg" style="position: relative; z-index: 8;">    
<img class="zoom2" src="http://kids.int/img/p/1/5/15-home_default.jpg" style="position: absolute; z-index: 20; display: block; left: 1127px; top: 581px;">
```

Comment: what's not working? Where is the css/javascript or whatever you'r using to show the zoom?

Comment: As i understand I need to dowload in zoom2 another image 15-large_default but how?

Comment: http://www.sunsean.com/zoomi/zoomi.js